# Get data from topic after pushing in @EmbeddedKafka in spring boot Junit

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka, embedded-kafka, spring-kafka-test

I am writing Junit test cases(using @EmbeddedKafka) for my Spring Boot application which extensively uses Spring-kafka to communicate with other services and for other operations.

One typical case is deleting the data from kafka (which we are doing with pushing **null** message in kafka).

Currently in delete() method we are doing this by first checking if there exist any message in kafka that is requested to be deleted.
Then we push **null** for that message key in Kafka

Steps followed in writing Junit for above method logic.

```
@Test
public void test(){
   //Push a message to Kafka (id=1234)
   //call test method service.delete(1234);
       //internally service.delete(1234) checks/validate whether message exists in kafka and then push null to delete topic.
  //check delete topic for delete message received.
  // Assertions
}
```

Problem here is Kafka always throws message not found exception. inside service.delete() method.

while checking logs in console. i figured out that my producer-config using a different port for kafka while consumer config using a diferent port.

I am not sure whether i have missed some minute detail or what is the reason for this behaviour.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to show all of your configuration (and the logs).

Comment: See my answer, please.

Answer (score 1):

I have this simple Spring Boot app for you to consider:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootEmbeddedKafkaApplication {

    public static final String MY_TOPIC = "myTopic";

    public BlockingQueue<String> kafkaMessages = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootEmbeddedKafkaApplication.class, args);
    }

    @KafkaListener(topics = MY_TOPIC)
    public void listener(String payload) {
        this.kafkaMessages.add(payload);
    }

}
```

The `application.properties`:

```
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=myGroup
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
```

And test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(properties =
        "spring.kafka.bootstrapServers:${" + EmbeddedKafkaBroker.SPRING_EMBEDDED_KAFKA_BROKERS + "}")
@EmbeddedKafka(topics = SpringBootEmbeddedKafkaApplication.MY_TOPIC)
public class SpringBootEmbeddedKafkaApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<Object, String> kafkaTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private SpringBootEmbeddedKafkaApplication kafkaApplication;

    @Test
    public void testListenerWithEmbeddedKafka() throws InterruptedException {
        String testMessage = "foo";
        this.kafkaTemplate.send(SpringBootEmbeddedKafkaApplication.MY_TOPIC, testMessage);

        assertThat(this.kafkaApplication.kafkaMessages.poll(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)).isEqualTo(testMessage);
    }

}
```

Pay attention to the `spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest` to let consumer to read from the beginning of the partition.

Also another important option to apply in the test is this:

```
@SpringBootTest(properties =
        "spring.kafka.bootstrapServers:${" + EmbeddedKafkaBroker.SPRING_EMBEDDED_KAFKA_BROKERS + "}")
```

The `@EmbeddedKafka` populates a `spring.embedded.kafka.brokers` system property and make Spring Boot auto-configuration to know about that we need to copy its value to the `spring.kafka.bootstrapServers` configuration property.

Or another option according our [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.2.3.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#_embedded_broker_in_literal_springboottest_literal_s):

```
static {
    System.setProperty(EmbeddedKafkaBroker.BROKER_LIST_PROPERTY, "spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers");
}
```

Comment: Let me try this